# Hash a 17 char key into 4 bytes value

Tags: algorithm, hash

I have a colleague struggling with a hashing problem.

There is a 17-alphanumeric valued key (a VIN code) that needs to be converted into a 4 byte value (could be alphanumeric as well). Knowing that those 4 bytes will limit the number of keys, what perfect-hash algorithm would you see for this problem?

Comment: 4 bytes will only limit the keys if you're actually trying to uniquely encode the VIN into the 4 bytes. Do you *need* uniqueness?

Comment: Maybe this hw is about chained-hashing?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yep I am aware that the 4 bytes will limit (a lot the number of key that might be hash), and yes the uniqueness is something really required. Unless it's impossible, which case a "almost perfect hash" might work, not sure though.

Comment: A perfect hash is only possible in this case if you don't want to hash any arbitrary combination of 17 digits, but only a limited list of keys all known in advance.  Is that what you have?

Comment: Vincent: It's clearly impossible - if you've got 36^17 possible keys (or worse 62^17 keys), and 2^32 possible results, that's more results than keys. Given that there are more possible keys than results, could you clarify how you're hoping to handle that? It's not really clear what you're asking for at the moment.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yep you are right, I comment on Dante jiang answer about it, the fact that the Vin number is specially formatted should help the process. Sorry, I didn't really thought about make this clear first, step up too quickly for my colleague ;) Thank you.

Comment: If you want a unique encoding, it's an encoding, not a hash. Judging by the Wikipedia article, there are many encodings for VINs, so you can't really rely on any one encoding. It's not going to be possible to fit this uniquely in 4 bytes. Why does this have to be 4 bytes long?

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Yes you are right, I first focused on "hash" cause of what my colleague told me, but it's in fact an encoding. The 4 bytes long is "just" a requirement from what I know. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Number#Components_of_the_VIN), I think you could first "compress" the key, or in other word, you do hash in 2 stages.

Stage 1: break down the key to individual parts according to the standard, and do customized hash independently.

Stage 2: Get hashes together, and do a normal hash.

An naive example:

If your data is limited to United States, there is only 27 possibility of the first 2 bytes, so the first 2 bytes can be hashed to 0 - 26. (Suppose we get `a` here.)

Then suppose other bytes have N possibilities, and can be hashed to 0 - N-1. (Suppose we get `b` here.)

The combinational result can be `a * N + b`. Then do a normal hash (if 26 * N > what 4 bytes can express).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am sorry I didn't had time to think about it so much before asking, but yes it seems simpler to do a "manual" hash based on the values than the VIN number contains, which are limited. My bad.

Comment: @Vincent B., I have edited a little bit (in case you did not see my updated answer when you replied).

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about a Hash function, so it is ok to have f(x0) == f(x1) with x0 != x1.

A good hash function should have the hashed values homogeneously distributed.
You can add the groups of 4 bytes which compose the 17-digit value together, and only keep the remaining 4 bytes with the lowest weight, for example.